# D3.js not appending updated tree in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, d3.js

I am using `D3.js Drag and Drop tree` in `angular js`. It is working fine but whenever I am visting any link which changes the json input for d3.js which must changed the tree at front end but its not happening. The update function of d3 is called but its not updating tree in frontend.

Here is demo plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Goe2xT0ZIZH4JGEaHUeN?p=preview  I have created. Here you can see on first time `Home`  as the parent node but when you click on link to change input json the tree is not updated , you can check in console that update function called.

Here is the link of my reference http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the new SVG is being appended to the container, and since there is a white background, the first graph remains on top. All you need to do is clean the container by changing line 149 of `dndtree.js` to `var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").html("").append("svg")`, where `html("")` cleans it up. You can also clean the container beforehand elsewhere.

Comment: yes , I was too thinking about the same issue and tried to make container empty using angular ng-if but that doesn't work . Anyway thanks for the help